# WebDriver.io's Visual Regression - Keep reference images consistent

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

Not really an issue, just rather a discussion/advice:

My current company wanted to an automation framework in their future projects and I proposed Webdriver.io. They seemed to like it, specifically the Visual Regression service (awesome feature btw!).

However, one thing I wanted to know is what would be the best practice to have the reference images be consistent throughout every developer's local computer?

In other words, if we have a GitHub repository of a project, and it has several reference images, what can we do to ensure that when developers fork that repository, the reference images will remain untouched in their local computers? In doing so, it will help ensure that any changes on the styling can be detected via Visual Regression.

I am sure this is not entirely related to Visual Regression but wanted to know what practices/methods you've guys used with it at a higher scale project, especially when you have multiple developers working on the same project.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version control system like Git, I recommend storing baseline images in it like any other file (although you may want to use a .gitignore file to skip the regression and diff images). This makes it simple to share baseline images across teams. It also allows for changes in the baseline to be tracked over time and viewed in pull requests.

Be aware that if team members or testing platforms are not using the same OS, the baseline images might differ slightly. A common example is that a baseline will work for local testing on OSX, but the same baseline image fails when TravisCI runs the same visual regression test since it is Linux-based. A tool like Sauce Labs can be really helpful with consistency of testing platform.

There are also admin panels out there like [Spectre](https://github.com/wearefriday/spectre) or [Percy.io](https://percy.io/), which have some WebdriverIO integration. I have [a live-stream video on Spectre](https://youtu.be/JL_WxMfs-KI?t=4m52s) if you're interested.